# How to fetch link name to next page in php?

Tags: php, html

This is my code:

```
    <?php
          require("../EmptyPHP.php");
          $query = "SELECT name, id FROM bank"; 
          $result = mysql_query($query);
          echo "<table style=width:40% border=1>"; 
          echo "<tr>
          <td width=50%>BANK NAME</td>
          <td width=50%>BANK ID</td>
          </tr>";
           while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
           echo "<tr><td >" . $row['name'] . "</td><td><a name=detail    
           href=viewDetails.php >" . $row['id'] . "</a></td></tr>";
          }
          echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

I get bank name and bank id as output, and I have to make when I click on particular bank id , that id has to be displayed in the next page i.e viewDetails.php .. so how to make that?

Comment: you can pass id with URL and access that id on viewDetails with GET method..and call query for getting result from that id or pass name and id both to viewDetails page with URL too..

Answer (score 1):

try below code and make sure the location/path of view details page is right.Otherwise change your path.

```
<?php
      require("../EmptyPHP.php");
      $query = "SELECT name, id FROM banktb"; 
      $result = mysql_query($query);
      echo "<table style=width:40% border=1>"; 
      echo "<tr>
      <td width=50%>BANK NAME</td>
      <td width=50%>BANK ID</td>
      </tr>";
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
       echo "<tr><td >" . $row['name'] . "</td><td><a id='detail' name='detail' href='#'>" . $row['id'] . "</a></td></tr>";
      }
      echo "</table>";
?>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#detail").click(function(){
var getval=this.text;
this.href="viewDetails.php?"+getval;
});
});
</script>
```

now you will get id of particular click in viewdetail page..Now you have to get that particular id via get method and then fetch data of particular id using sql query.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the id through url like:

```
   "</td><td><a name=detail href=viewDetails.php?id=".$row['id'].">" . $row['id'] . "</a>
```

and can access it in the viewDetails.php page with

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$_GET[];` in your case.

add this to your php code

```
viewDetails.php?bankname=$row['name']&bankid=$row['id']
```

and in your `viewDetails.php` you have to get those variables using.

```
echo $name = $_GET['bankname'];
echo $id = $_GET['bankid'];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm glad you made it friend! Mark this question as answered so other can refer to it.